# Is there a Latin construction for "she must be" as in "I bet she is"/"She probably is"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

Say my friend is supposed to meet me, but she's late, and I think it's because she was reading, I might say, "She must have been reading."

Is there a way to express this in Latin other than something like *Veri similiter legebat* or *Eam puto legisse*? If so, what is it? Surely not *Legisse debet*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, verbs translatable as "must", such as *debet*, *necesse est* and particularly *oportet*, do often express this type of [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) (as opposed to [deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality)) meaning in Latin.

This [book chapter](https://books.google.com/books?id=301Z90W3gOUC&lpg=PA199&ots=Mo2p7eMrE9&dq=epistemic%20modality%20latin&pg=PA193#v=onepage&q&f=false) on "Mood and Modality" by Elisabetta Magni contains a large number of examples, as well as some statistics on the frequency of such usages for different verbs. Some examples:

- *hasce aedis esse **oportet**, Demaenetus ubi dicitur habitare* "This must be the house where D. is said to live" (Plaut. *Asin.* 381-2)
- *hic nescio quid boni **debet** esse* "There must be something good here" (Petron. 33.8.3)
- *quando quidem totis mortalibus adsimulata ipsa quoque ex aliis **debent** constare elementis* "since they resemble all mankind, they too must consist of other elements" (Lucr. 2.980-1)
- *sed magnum nescioquid **necessest** evenisse* "but something  of consequence must have happened" (Ter. *Hec.* 304)
- *haud longe abesse **oportet*** "he must not be far away" (Plaut. *Amph.* 322)
- *prodigum te fuisse **oportet** in adulescentia* "you must have been a spendthrift in your youth" (Plaut. *Amph.* 1031)

Comment: +1. Should note that even in English, "ought" and "should" care often epistemic, so it isn't necessary to translate them in Latin as "must" every time.

Comment: I'm curious about Joel's example sentence: would you write *eam legisse opportet* or *legere debebat*, or something else?

Comment: @brianpck, the former seems more likely as, in all these examples at least, the main verb is in the present tense while the time of the event itself is expressed by the tense of the infinitive.